VSCode fails to update typescript imports on file move on MacOs
I have a mixed js / ts project that I'm migrating to ts. The server runs on aws lambda, and I have a tsconfig at root, and one at /lambdas.
Whenever I move a typescript file, VSCode asks if I want to update imports, and I select yes. This fixes imports in the file that is moved, but does not fix any of the imports for those that have the file as a dependency. JS imports successfully change other files that are js, but not ts (I have a jsconfig as well).
Any guess as to what's misconfigured?
Relevant file structure below. The moves are made in lambdas/routes to subfolders.
-- lib
  tsconfig.json
-- lambdas
tsconfig.json

tsconfig (both are currently the same)
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cdk.out"]
}

Example failed update, in lambdas/tests
import { makeBiFriendship, makeUniFriendship } from '../routes/users_ts'; // should be ../routes/users/users_ts


Partial solution: It appears that the issue with ts import updates is that I neglected to set a outDir, so my generated files are mixed in with my source code (the outDir is new). When I moved both the users_ts.d.ts and users_ts.js, on the final move, imports updated successfully.
However, moving js files update corresponding js imports, but not imports in ts files.

this sounds potentially like a user papercut that would warrant an issue ticket to have the maintainers take a look. if you raise an issue ticket, add a link to it here.
